# is it possible to save generated wsdl stub classes to disk using SUDs in python

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, sublimetext2, suds

I have a wsdl that takes a lot of time to get processed using SUDS.

```
client = Client(url)
```

Now is there a way i can save generated client classes from python to disk(i tried using cPickle but it gives error as this protocol is meant to save instances and the **typeof** client is a **class**)?
The reason i want to save is to utilize the generated stub classes to ship these with a py module(a plugin that i am writing for sublime editor and in my case WSDL is quite static and takes hell lot of time to get loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Suds has a caching options that you can use on client creation:

```
from suds.cache import ObjectCache

oc = ObjectCache(days=0)
client = Client(url, cache=oc, cachingpolicy=1)
```

Caching policy description from suds documentation:

> **cachingpolicy**
>
> The caching policy, determines how data is cached. The default is 0. version 0.4+
>
> - 0 = XML documents such as WSDL & XSD.
> - 1 = WSDL object graph.